# java.lang.IllegalStateException: (Activity has been destroyed) in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

In my app I have 2 fragments: `fragmentDiary` and `fragmentCal` . I'm trying to call `fragmentDiary` from `fragmentCal` . I've made a function `callFragmentDiary()` for this purpose in `MainActivity` . So, from `fragmentCal`, this function,present in MainActivity is called. Then this function calls `fragmentDiary` from MainActivity. However I'm getting the `java.lang.IllegalStateException` on the following line in this function.

```
 ft.replace(R.id.container , fragDiary).commit();
```

Following is the relevant code:

**In fragmentCal.java**

```
( new MainActivity()).callFragmentDiary(date);
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.nirvan.finaldiary;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  fragmentDiary fragDiary = new fragmentDiary();
  fragmentCal fragCal = new fragmentCal();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ft.add(R.id.container,fragCal).commit();
  }

  public void callFragmentDiary(int []date){
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("day",date[0]);
    bundle.putInt("month",date[1]);

    fragDiary.setArguments(bundle);
    ft.replace(R.id.container , fragDiary).commit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You instantiating a `(new MainActivity). callFragmentDiary` in the cast, while it should be something like `((MainActivity)getActivity()).callFragmentdiary`.

Also, it might be a good idea to get the `FragmentManager` inside the `onCreate` method, as the fragment manager might not be setup when the class is loaded/instantiated. And create the `FragmentTransaction` only when you are going to use it.

Comment: Why does this work? What's wrong with `(new MainActivity).callFragmentDiary` ? Why can't I create an object of `MainActivity` and use that to access the functions in it?

Comment: Because Activities are instantiated by the Android Framework. You should never instantiated them yourself. You are calling the method `callFragmentDiary` on the new instance, instead of the instance that you are running the code in.